# Broadcom CA Workstation - Making an APPL WAIT while another APPL is EXECUTING

Tags: workload-scheduler, broadcom

I am working with Broadcom CA workload automation. Lets say there is an APPL ABC which is currently EXECUTING. There is another APPL XYZ whose schedule has arrived and its triggered, but it has to wait for ABC to COMPLETE before it can start execution. How to configure this?

I tried using NOTWITH (ABC/-) HOLD condition on APPL XYZ and vice versa. But it didn't work.

Please suggest.